# Create output diagnostics similar to devtools::check() (color and loading symbols)

Tags: r, devtools, r-package, testthat

I want to create a function that runs some checks and returns diagnostics to terminal in a similar fashion as `devtools::check()` does.

devtools uses colours, multiple other symbols (loading and "check" to name a few).

Is there a way I could design/write my diagnostics to be like that?

[image: example]

Answer (score 6):

I can't find **the** answer in the source code but I guess it is a combination of `crayon` and uft8 symbols. But I can't find which symbols are used for the loading so I used different ones.

```
library(crayon)

for (i in letters[1:10])
{
  cat("\u2022", "| 0 text", i, "\r")
  flush.console()

  for (j in 1:sample(2:9,1))
  {
    if (j %% 2)
      cat("\u2059", "|", j,  "text", i, "\r")
    else
      cat("\u2058", "|", j, "text", i, "\r")

    flush.console()

    Sys.sleep(0.3)
  }

  if (runif(1) < 0.66)
    cat(green("\u2713"), "|", j, "text", i, "\n")
  else
    cat(red("\u2717"), "|", j, "text", i, "\n")
}
```